# Cannot See Values While Debugging ASP.NET Core

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging an ASP.NET Core application, using Visual Studio 2015, I cannot see the variable, parameters and field values, when, for example, I hover them. I cannot add them to the watch as well. I am running in debug.

Comment: Are you running on CoreCLR or Desktop? What VS version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate, targetting both .NET Core and Desktop.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. In the about page, look for the full VS build number. Also share the web tools package version which is on the same page

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 CTP
Version 14.0.25008.00 Update 2 CTP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055
Installed Version: Enterprise

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)   14.1.20203.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)

Comment: Myself and a colleague of mine are having the same issue. I'm also using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 CTP (version 14.0.25008.00 Update 2 CTP), my colleague uses the Community edition. We tried safe mode and that didn't help. Reported via the tools in VS.

Comment: Thanks, nice to see that I'm not alone! :-)

Comment: We tried playing around with the dnvm changing the runtime and architecture, but no joy. Also happens in a clean project.

Comment: I asked Microsoft directly, but got no response, yet...

Comment: To be fair, it's a CTP and they clearly stated they will not support it. "We do not advise that you use it in a production environment." and of course I ignored their advice, because why not? Wel...

Comment: Well, if nobody tries it, then who will spot these problems? :-)

Comment: Can you check if it works with VS2015 Update 1?

Comment: What do you mean update 1? The debugging worked fine in update 1 (and its CTP) until we updated.

Comment: I wasn't sure of that.

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci any updates on this issue?

Comment: It has been reported to Microsoft, but no dates yet.

Comment: I'm curious. Did you got a chance to try out Update 2 RC yet? This update has resolved the issue entirely for us. No 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode' necessity. :)

Comment: I am using it, but it didn't resolve anything, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior happens with 1.0.0-rc1-update1, but not with 1.0.0-rc2-16357.
If possible, upgrade. Microsoft is aware of it.

Comment: This update attempts to fix it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695655.aspx

Answer (score 7):

We might have found a solution (or at least a workaround) for the problem. If we go into `Tools > Options > Debugging` and enable `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` then we can inspect all the values we like.

I hope this solves the issue for you as well.

Update: Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 RC fixed the issue for me, but unfortunately not for the OP.

Comment: Thanks! Enabling `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` works for me on Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 RC

Comment: this technique worked for me on VS 2019.. thanks