# Visual Studio 2017 cannot inspect variable values on Razor Page View when debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm working with ASP.NET core 2.0. When debugging, I want to inspect the values of some variables on my razor views, however it's not showing the values when I mouse over them, it just shows the variables Type, like it would when not debugging.

I found the following question posted over 2 years ago with the same problem in VS2015, however the suggestions there have not worked for me, it also suggested it was a known problem, and was to be fixed in a VS2015 update.

'Use Managed Compatibility mode' under Tools->Options-Debugging didn't solve it.

I'm running VS2017 Community v15.7.2

[Cannot See Values While Debugging ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543354/cannot-see-values-while-debugging-asp-net-core)

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint to the specific line? Does it hit the breakpoint? As far as I know, the latest VS2017 version would be the 15.7.2 now, how about using the latest version?

Comment: Apologies, I read the wrong version number, that was my .NET Framework version number, oops. I am on 15.7.2. When setting a breakpoint it does hit it, but when hovering over a variable, it just shows the type, not its current value.

This is only the case in my views, when the code steps into a controller or otherwise, I see the values, it's working as expected there.

Comment: You could right-click and choose "Add Watch".  The Watch Window usually works perfectly - as a workaround until you get things solved.

Comment: Thanks Sam, that does the trick for a workaround

Comment: @Ryan B., Glad to know that it works well even if it was a workaround, but as far as I know, datatips could visualize complex Data Types, if you want to view the value, we often use the debug watch windows.

Comment: This was working in 2013. I would like a way for this to work in 2017. It is a pain to have to move things to the watch window to see values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 7/3 this appears to be a known issue with a fix in the works.  See (now closed) [Visual Studio bug #249225](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/249225/razor-debugging-doesnt-show-variable-value-on-hove.html), and it's linked item [Visual Studio Bug #246728](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246728/vs2017-1570-community-debugger-not-showing-variabl.html).  Consensus appears to be that this broke in the 15.7+ builds, with recommendations to use the watch window as commented above or downgrade to a 15.6 build as potential workarounds.

On the linked ticket, [recent comment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/284514/view.html) indicates it may be fixed with the 15.8 preview, so work is ongoing.

Hope this helps anyone else who wanders by!